# OpenID Single Sign On - Change Authentication Flow

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, jwt, open-id-connect

I have an Auth Provider created with OpenID and everything is working good.

But, I would like to change the Authentication Flow from `web server` to `user-agent`

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_using_id_token.htm&type=5

Basically, all initial requests *(redirects 302)* that Salesforce sends to the IDP *(Identity Provider)* during the authentication have the `response_type` set to `code`, which designates the [**Web Server Flor**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5).

Is there a way to change the `response_type` to `token` or `token id_token`, which designates the [**User-Agent Flow**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5)?